# Cannot get data into Vue component from Vuex store using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, vuex

I am having trouble getting data into my Vue component using Typescript. After logging in I make an API call to get some data. Once the data is returned I am using a Vuex module to store the data.

```
@Action async getData(): Promise<TODO> {
  return new Promise<TODO>((resolve, reject) => { 
    getData("getData").then(res => {
       if(res) {
         console.log('Result -> ', res) // Data is here
         this.items = res // store the response in a module variable
         resolve()
       }
      ...
     })
```

When I navigate to another Vue page I call the following function on the same store module inside `created()`. I made it async/await because I thought that was causing the issue.

```
 async created() {
    const storeData = await classesModule.getItems 
    this.myData = storeData
    console.log('Data in Created -> ', this.myData) // Nothing here
 }
```

Here is the getter in the store

```
get getItems() {
    console.log('GET THE ITEMS object -> ', this.items) // Nothing here   
    return this.items
  }
```

Both of the console.log lines above produce the same result in the console, which is the following:

```
[__ob__: Ot]
length: 0
__ob__: Ot {value: Array(0), dep: _t, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Array
```

There is no data, just an empty array.

If anyone can help me with this I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: I think you forgot to call the function `getItems`, at least when you copied it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you call `reject` if there was no response?

Comment: @caTS getItems is called here  `async created() {
    const storeData = await classesModule.getItems ...}`. This part works fine.

Comment: Consider using codesandbox.io or similar to show us what you have so far. The code included in the question is far from sufficient to figure out what's not working (e.g: where are you defining the `getData` function called inside the `getData` action?). You're also not saying which vuex typescript plugin you're using. Each has a slightly different syntax. Last, but not least, `vuex` is deprecated and the official recommended state mgmt plugin is `pinia`, even for vue 2. Pinia handles TypeScript gracefully and intuitively, without needing any extra plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
getters: {

  getItems(state) {
    console.log('GET THE ITEMS object -> ', state.items) 
    return state.items
  }
}
state:{
     items:[]
}
```

the first param of getters is state. you can access it from that.

Comment: I am using TypeScript, so the Vuex syntax is completely different from the regular JS, where you need to pass `state` around explicitly. So sadly this is not the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. i am not aware of that.